# How to use send.redirect() while working with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I was trying to redirect to a dynamic page from Interceptors and Handler Mapping program. I have already defined a controller which handles and redirects (/hello.htm) through model (I have only this controller in my program). Until this point it is working fine. Apart from this, I registered a handler which will redirect to a page once it satisfies some condition.

```
public class WorkingHoursInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter  {
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("In Working Hours Interceptor-pre");
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    if(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<10||c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>20){
        response.sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/jsp/failure.jsp");
                        return false;
    }
    return true;
..............
..............
}
```

But once it comes to `response.sendRedirect`, it is showing resource not found even though the mentioned page is present. I tried to redirect to `"WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp"` as well but keeps showing the same error. If the condition in the interceptor is not satisfied, the program works fine.

Below is shown the only controller present in the program.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
@RequestMapping("/hello.htm")
public ModelAndView sayGreeting(){
    String msg="Hi, Welcome to Spring MVC 3.2";
    return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp","message",msg);

    }

}
```

(The controller for handling `hello.html` works fine if I change the interceptor condition)

Instead of redirecting, if I just print a message in the console, the program works fine. But once it comes to redirect it shows the error. Do I need to specify a separate controller to handle this request? Will this redirection request go to the dispatcher-servlet?

Comment: Hi All, Instead of redirecting; if I am just printing a message in console, program is working fine. But once it comes to redirect it is showing error. Do i need to specify separate controller to handle this request?Will this redirection request go to dispatcher-servlet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `redirect:` prefix in the view name, the code for redirect will look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String redirect() {

      return "redirect:finalPage";
   }
```

OR

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirect() {

  return new ModelAndView("redirect:finalPage");
}
```

You may get a detail description from here:
[enter link description here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_page_redirection_example.htm)